# jscript/jquery: fade in divs 1 by 1, with pause inbetween

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am totally stumped here.

I have a bunch of messages, each within a div "msg_feed_frame_$i" which increases, so message 1 is in div "msg_feed_frame_1", msg 2 is in "msg_feed_frame_2", etc etc. I want to fade these messages in one by one using jquery, but for some reason no matter what I do with settimeout and setinterval, the code immediately fades them all in simultaneously.

This is what i've got so far:

```
function feed(i)
{
    var div = "#msg_feed_frame_";
    var fader = div.concat(i);
    $(fader).fadeIn(2000);

}

function timefade()
{
var num = 1;
for (num=1; num<=10; num++)
{
var t=setTimeout(feed(num),1000);
}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        timefade();
    });
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, please format you code correctly (did it for you this time). To learn how to do it, please click the orange question mark in the ask question text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `for` loop executes quickly and sets a timeout 1000ms from now for each function call. Here's one way you could remedy this:

```
function feed(i) {
    var div = "#msg_feed_frame_";
    var fader = div.concat(i);
    $(fader).fadeIn(2000);

}

function timefade() {
    var num = 1;
    var fadeIt = function(i) {
        return function() { feed(i); };
    };
    for (num = 1; num <= 4; num++) {
        var t = setTimeout(fadeIt(num), num * 1000);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    timefade();
});
```

Additionally, your original code was passing `setTimeout` the *results* of the `feed(i)` function call (`undefined`), and it expects an object of type `function`. I added a helper function that returns a reference to a function that will call `feed` with the correct argument.

Capturing the value of `num` inside a function is called a closure, and it can be confusing at first. Check [this post out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/497356) for some good explanations of closures inside loops and while they're necessary.

Here's your example, working: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/tpGXt/

Comment: Great code, thank you. Is there any way to reverse the loop, so that it feeds out msg4, msg3, msg2,msg1?

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's .delay() function...

```
    function feed(i){
    var div = "#msg_feed_frame_";
    var fader = div.concat(i);
    $(fader).fadeIn(2000).delay(1000);
}
function timefade(){
 var num = 1;
 for (num=1; num<=10; num++){
   feed(num);
 }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
        timefade();
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work-- that fades in again, all of the DIVs simultaneously.